# (as3) URLloader keeping connection alive

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, connection, urlloader

I have a little problem with a simple URLLoader, it simply just loads the data from an url, and processes that data, nothing complicated. But, when ever i run it, it leaves the connection open. At the bottom of the browser it says:

> Transfering Data From www....

The data is read sucessfully, so it should close the connection? but doesnt seem to want to do it. Is there anyway to close all open connections, or somehow remove such message?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Been informed it might be a firefox issue only :\

Comment: Having same issue in firefox while loading xml using URLLoader

Answer (score 2):

there is a URLLoader.close() method that should do the trick: [LiveDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/URLLoader.html#close%28%29)